# Unable to initialize the environment variable in user environment generator in systemd

Tags: bash, systemd

I am using Arch linux and the windows manager BSPWM.

My login manager is Lightdm.

My systemd version

```
systemd 246.2-1
```

I am not using .xinitrc to start up process in my DM.

So i have .profile file which is shown below

```
set -a
source ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment
set +a
mkdir -p ${XDG_DATA_HOME}/wineprefixes
mkdir -p ${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg
gpg2 --homedir ${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg
mkdir -p ${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/less
```

In this you can see ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment which load my environment variables

${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
PATH="$(/usr/bin/du -L --exclude=.idea --exclude=archive --exclude=__pycache__ $HOME/.local/bin| /usr/bin/cut -f2 | /usr/bin/tr '\n' ':')$PATH"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/npm/bin
# default programs:
DM="$(/usr/bin/sed -n 's|Session=\(.*\)|\1|p' $HOME/.dmrc)"
EDITOR="emsc"
TERMINAL="st"
BROWSER="firefox"
FILE="lf"
STATUSBAR="polybar"
#Other program settings
VCONFIG="$HOME/.config/vconfig/"
VBIN="$HOME/.local/bin/vbin"
SUDO_ASKPASS="$VBIN/dmenupass"
ORGPATH=${HOME}/Org

#XDG CONFIG MOVEMENTS
XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
XDG_DATA_HOME="$HOME/.local/share"
XDG_CACHE_HOME="$HOME/.cache"

IPYTHONDIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/jupyter
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/jupyter
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/android
ADB_VENDOR_KEY=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/android
ZDOTDIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/.config/zsh
NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/npm/config
LESSKEY=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/less/lesskey
GTK2_RC_FILES=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/java

WINEPREFIX=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/wineprefixes/default
HISTFILE=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/zsh/history
_Z_DATA=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/z
GOPATH=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/go
GNUPGHOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg


NUGET_PACKAGES=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/NuGetPackages
PYLINTHOME=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/pylint
LESSHISTFILE=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/less/history
CUDA_CACHE_PATH=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/nv
```

Now my issue is i am trying to start systemd to start up certain user specific systemd service.

I came to know systemd will not have any environment variable which is setup during the startup.

I had three options in front of me, when search internet. Please correct, if any other alternate way for this.

1. EnvironmentFile or Environment property in service file. But i got an issue with variable expansion in this approach.
2. using ~/.config/environment.d Keeping the file .conf here and it will be automatically taken care, But i end up with same issue.
3. use systemd "user environment generator" For this i need to keep the shell script in this location. /usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/

What i thought was i will reading my environment file using below command and creator a generator script.

```
cat ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment|while read line; do
 echo $line
done
```

I even tried with

```
set -a
source ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment.
set +a
```

But i was not getting any environment variable when i type

```
systemctl --user show-environment
```

I tried to do daemon reload. And also restarted the machine.

```
  systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

The above ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment is working without any issue when i login and profie getting initialize in bash. But inside the user environment generator not working.

Please let me know any more details required on this.

Basically i want to initial the same all environment variable which is present ${HOME}/.config/vconfig/venvironment on user environment generator in systemd

Comment: Who is setting `${HOME}`? You probably need to set it first before referencing to it  `[Service]` `Environment=HOME=/home/foo`

Comment: Michael , when type systemctl --user show-environment I am able to see the $HOME  is having a valid value as /home/vipin

Comment: I even tried echo "testhome=$HOME" when I do systemctl --user show-environment it is showing testhome=/home/vipin

Comment: For your information i am setting environment variable using "user environment generator"

Comment: What does `tty` command return in this context? (I guess it is supposed to run right after you've logged on in xdm.)

Comment: I tried doing in generator echo "testtty=$(tty)"  I got an out put when I type systemctl --user show-environment testtty=$'not a tty'